# Check to see if two Ms-Access reports match in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Are there any ways in VBA to check the contents in two access reports to see if they both match?

A less ideal way to do this is to export both reports as a PDF using

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptMyReport", acFormatPDF, "C:\Reports\MyReport.pdf"
```

and then have a pdf compare tools such as WinMerge with the xdocdiff plugin analyze the difference. It's not a very streamlined process.

I'm trying to unit test each report by comparing the output of a newer version to an older version of the report to see if anything broke or changed.

Comment: There is always a way, but not with limited data. Can you provide sample data? or a least list the fields included on the reports? are the reports based off the same query? or different queries? are any calculations done on the report itself or is everything handled by a query?

Comment: Does the solution have to VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question. A way to do this is to export your reports as html files using the DoCmd.OutputTo and then read them into a string variable. You can then compare string together from the newer file and older file.

Here is an example code:

```
Public Function fncCheckMatchingReports(strPathOne As String, strPathTwo As String)

    Dim oFSO As Object, oFS1 As Object, oFS2 As Object
    Dim sText1 As String, sText2 As String

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set oFS1 = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\test.html")
    'Set oFS2 = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\test2.html")
    Set oFS1 = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strPathOne)
    Set oFS2 = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strPathTwo)

    sText1 = oFS1.ReadAll()
    sText2 = oFS2.ReadAll()

    If sText1 = sText2 Then
        fncCheckMatchingReports = True
    Else
        fncCheckMatchingReports = False
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to come down to old-fashioned debugging techniques like inserting temporary subtotal fields and other points of comparison.